# Laravel 5.1 Upload Files Security

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1

How can I set a security in my upload files that only pdf, doc, jpeg, png and docx can be uploaded?

I'm just trying it but I don't know if it is the right thing to do... just experimenting.. ^_^ But after all it didn't function ^^ ... actually i've got an error.. Try to help me guys for this?

Here's my Controller.php

```
public function index()
{
    $entries = Fileentry::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('fileentries.index', compact('entries'));
}

public function store(UploadFiles $request)
{
    if($request->file('filename')) 
    {
        $file = $request->file('filename');

        $filename           = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
        $fileExt            = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mime               = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $original_filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $description        = UploadFiles::input('description');
        $user_id            = Auth::user()->id;
        $file->save();

        // Move the file now
        $updatedFileName = $filename.'.'.$fileExt;
        $file->move('path/to/destination/folder', $updatedFileName);

     return redirect('upload');
    }

    else
    {
        echo "nothing happen";
    }
}
```

Here's my View.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<form action="{{route('addentry', [])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <input type="file" name="filefield" required>
    <br>

    Description <br>
    <input type="textarea" name="description">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<h1> List of your Entries</h1>

<div class="row">
    <ul class="thumbnails">

@foreach($entries as $entry)

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="{{route('getentry', $entry->filename ) }}" alt="ALT NAME" class="img-responsive" /> 

                     <p>{{ $entry->description }} </p>

                     <a href="{{ URL::to('download') }}" download="{{$entry->original_filename}}">{{$entry->original_filename}}</a>

            </div>
        </div>


 @endforeach
 </ul>
 </div>


nI@endsection
```

Thank you guys in advance ^^

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-mimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `FormRequest` object by issuing the following command:

```
php artisan make:request YourFormRequest
```

Now, in your rules method:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx',
        // and other validation rules...
    ];
}
```

Now update your controller:

```
/**
 * Store the form values.
 * Don't forget to import the YourFormRequest class
 *
 * @param \App\Http\Requests\YourFormRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Redirect|string
 */
public function store(YourFormRequest $request)
{
    if($request->file('filename')) {
        $file = $request->file('filename');

        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExt  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileMime = $file->getClientMimeType();

        // and rest of the file details

        // Move the file now
        $updatedFileName = $fileName.'.'.$fileExt;
        $file->move('path/to/destination/folder', $updatedFileName);

        // or using the Storage class, it is the same
        // as what you have written.
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

In your `YourFormRequest` file, replace the authorize method:

```
/**
 * Authorize the request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true; // replace false with true.
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Cheers.

Comment: I've tried this sir but i've got an error..  " Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::file() "

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the code that I have written above ? Asking because, it is absolutely correct. I have tried and tested it on my machine.. I hope you have updated the store method with the above code.

Comment: yes sir..i've use it and now, whenever i upload a file , i've got error "Forbidden"

Comment: hello sir i've tried it sir but i've got a blank page..as in whole white nothing is written... T___T

Comment: Kindly update the question and please show me the `store` method what have you written ?

Comment: i'm so sorry sir if i don't know how to update my store method...hmm...i already updated my question sir in updated store method..

Comment: i'm so sorry sir if i don't know how to update my store method...hmm...i already updated my question sir in updated store method.