# Laravel file upload security

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

When I upload a file in laravel i can check mimes type and set size of file by validation
**i.e-'image'=> 'mimes:pdf|max:5000'**
but still I am not able to check double extension(ex- abc.text.pdf).
How can I do that any suggession..

Comment: well you cannot do that in the validation provided by laravel, for that you need to check manually

Comment: this try
[Upload Files Security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348740/6650162)

Comment: @Exprator  I want to upload only PDF file, So laravel default validation is not enough to  prevent file other than PDF, So how can I check it manually. Anybody can explain